# Why is the trace on my DSO displaying faintly (too light) at longer sweep rates?

Tags: oscilloscope

I am using a Rigol DS2102 (DS2000 series) DSO to monitor clock output on a microcontroller. For whatever reason, the trace intensity becomes very faint at 200ms/division sweep rates and longer.

I've tried increasing the trace/waveform draw intensity to 100%. I've tried turning on/off bandwidth limit, changing voltage per division, different input signals, and a number of other tweaks. It happens on both input channels. Notably, when changing the voltage per division setting, the trace is briefly displayed at the expected intensity. Once the sweep resumes, it returns to the barely-visible faint display.

It is running the latest firmware (03.05.SP4). I looked for errata and changes in the firmware but there's no mention of it.

Why is the trace displaying so faintly at 200ms/division and up?

[image: Faint trace at 1s/div]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check **memory depth**. Make sure you aren't using a low memory depth. At slower sweep rates, the number of samples needed to show high resolution is greater.

DSOs attempt to mimic analog appearance by varying the intensity of the drawn waveform based on the signal dwell time in a particular location. The longer the signal is present at a particular level, the brighter it appears on a phosphor-coated CRT display that legacy oscilloscopes used. Consider a square wave with a fast edge: The top and bottom of the wave will appear bright while the vertical transitions can be very faint.

The sample memory is utilized to interpret intensity. The more points clustered in a given area on the screen, the brighter the trace will be drawn. With long sweep times, the points stored using a given sample depth will be "spread out" more. The spread distance of those points are used to determine how intense to draw the trace. The oscilloscope's particular algorithm for comparing sample distance to screen pixel distance will determine the trace intensity.

Changing the sample depth to "Auto" or to its maximum of 14M points fixes the trace intensity for 200ms/div sweep rates and longer:

[image: Trace intensity corrected]

The vertical clock pulses are still faint because they are of very short duration with respect to the overall sweep time.